# Reshaping data in crosstab using stack or melt

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe containing columns UPC, date_expected, and quantity picked. Original data comes over with multiple UPCs per day (one row per order, multiple orders containing the same UPC in one day) but also not listing every date for every UPC, only listing the dates where the quantity picked is greater than 0. 
Goal: organize a dataframe showing quantity_picked by UPC then by date_expected, listing every date from 5/14/19 to current even when quantity_picked = 0 (lines showing quantity_picked = 0 not included in original data source).

```
MFC_order_daily['date_expected'] = pd.to_datetime(MFC_order_daily['date_expected'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
print('Daily Pick Data:')
print(MFC_order_daily)
```

Data comes over in this format:

```
Daily Pick Data:
                 UPC  quantity_picked date_expected
0      0001111041660              1.0    2019-05-14
1      0001111045045              1.0    2019-05-14
             ...              ...           ...
39694  0004470036000              6.0    2019-06-24
39695  0007225001116              1.0    2019-06-24

[39696 rows x 3 columns]
```

Attempted to organize using a groupby and reset_index as shown below, but received the following dataframe missing dates where quantity_picked=0:

```
tipd = MFC_order_daily.groupby(['UPC', 'date_expected']).sum().reset_index()
tipd = tipd[['UPC','date_expected','quantity_picked']]
print(tipd)
```

```
                 UPC date_expected  quantity_picked
0      0000000002554    2019-05-14              4.0
1      0001111041660    2019-05-14              2.0
2      0001111041660    2019-05-16              2.0
3      0004470036000    2019-05-14              3.0
4      0004470036000    2019-05-16              1.0
```

Then tried creating a crosstab to get the zero values and reshape using stack or melt. 
Successful creation of and resulting crosstab:

```
tipd2 = pd.crosstab([MFC_order_daily["UPC"]], MFC_order_daily["date_expected"])
print(tipd2)
```

```
date_expected  2019-05-14  2019-05-15  ...  2019-06-23  2019-06-24
UPC                                    ...                        
0000000002554           0           0  ...           0           0
0000000003082           0           1  ...           2           3
0000000003107           1           0  ...           2           2
                  ...         ...  ...         ...         ...
0360600051715           0           0  ...           0           0
0501072452748           0           0  ...           0           0
0880100551750           0           0  ...           0           0

[8302 rows x 42 columns]
```

Attempt to stack:

```
tipd2.stack('date_expected')
print('Stacked tipd2:')
print(tipd2)
```

### Resulting data is the same as the crosstab shown above, no change, no error.

Attempt to melt:

```
tipd2.melt(id_vars=['UPC', 'date_expected'])
```

Resulting error:

```
KeyError: "The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['UPC', 'date_expected']"
```

Desired Output:

```
                 UPC date_expected  quantity_picked
0      0000000002554    2019-05-14              4.0
1      0000000002554    2019-05-15              0.0
2      0000000002554    2019-05-16              0.0
3      0001111041660    2019-05-14              2.0
4      0001111041660    2019-05-15              0.0
5      0001111041660    2019-05-16              2.0
6      0004470036000    2019-05-14              3.0
7      0004470036000    2019-05-15              0.0
8      0004470036000    2019-05-16              1.0
```

Looping through every date from 5/14/19 forward for each UPC.

Comment: You should really give a short sample of your data and the expected output from **that sample**. That way, people will understand what you want better.

Comment: Do you want `df.groupby(['UPC', 'date_expected'])['quantity_picked'].sum().reset_index()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I tried to include as much of my data as possible without overloading the post. I'm working with a large amount of data and am trying to make sure I show enough without showing too much. What specifically do you mean by "that sample"? I put the expected output at the end like the template suggests.

Comment: @Erfan when I try that I get the same result I am already getting. It seems to be providing the sum of quantity picked by default. The only issue is that it is not reporting 0 values for the dates where a UPC was not picked (quantity_picked=0).

Comment: You expected output should be the result of the sample data. That is, people should be able to run their code on the sample data and compare that to the expected output. For example, if you are looking for the sum of the data, you should give sample like `1,2,3` and expected output `6`. You should not give sample like `1,2,100,...,1` and say you expect `100000`.

Comment: I will try to make the post easier to understand. One moment.

Comment: I have tried to better show a sample of the data. @QuangHoang please let me know if this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can make do with `pivot` and `stack`:

```
# this is after aggregation by `groupby().sum()`
df = pd.DataFrame({'UPC': ['0000000002554', '0001111041660', '0001111041660', 
                           '0004470036000', '0004470036000'],
 'date_expected': ['2019-05-14',
  '2019-05-14',
  '2019-05-16',
  '2019-05-14',
  '2019-05-16'],
 'quantity_picked': [4.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0]})


(df.pivot_table(index='UPC', 
          columns='date_expected', 
          values='quantity_picked',
          fill_value=0)
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
             UPC date_expected  0
0  0000000002554    2019-05-14  4
1  0000000002554    2019-05-16  0
2  0001111041660    2019-05-14  2
3  0001111041660    2019-05-16  2
4  0004470036000    2019-05-14  3
5  0004470036000    2019-05-16  1
```

If you want to fill the date as well, then you may want to take a look at `reindex`.

Comment: I believe you are correct on the recommendation of reindex, I need to fill the date so I suppose that is what I'm looking for. When I try the following: 

days = MFC_order_daily['date_expected'].unique()

days = pd.to_datetime(days, format='%Y-%m-%d')

tipd = MFC_order_daily.groupby(['UPC', 'date_expected']).sum().reindex(days).reset_index()

tipd = tipd[['UPC','date_expected','quantity_picked']]

print(tipd)

I get the following error: 

TypeError: Argument 'tuples' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got DatetimeArray)

Answer (score 0):

The `ignore_index=False` parameter in `pd.melt` is suitable for this situation

Demo code:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import random

df_letter = pd.DataFrame({'Upper' : [random.choice(string.ascii_letters[26:30]) for _ in range(100)],
                          'Lower' : [random.choice(string.ascii_letters[0:5]) for _ in range(100)]} )
```

the df_letter is

```
    Upper   Lower
0   A   a
1   B   b
2   D   b
3   C   c
4   D   e
```

then calculate the crosstab

```
df_cross = pd.crosstab(df_letter.Upper, df_letter.Lower)
```

the df_cross:

```
Lower   a   b   c   d   e
Upper                   
A   4   5   9   3   5
B   7   7   5   6   5
C   6   1   7   3   6
D   7   4   3   3   4
```

then you can call the `pd.melt` function with `ignore_index=False` parameter to reshape the dataframe

```
df_cross.melt(ignore_index=False)
```

the head of output:

```
    Lower   value
Upper       
A   a   4
B   a   7
C   a   6
D   a   7
A   b   5
```

Or you can add a index column first, then pass the `id_vars` parameter to `pd.melt`

```
df_cross['Upper'] = df_cross.index
df_cross.melt(id_vars='Upper')
```

the head of ouput:

```
    Upper   Lower   value
0   A   a   4
1   B   a   7
2   C   a   6
3   D   a   7
4   A   b   5
5   B   b   7
```